# Wordpress - Set Up Limit Categories in Breadcrumbs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code in my WP theme which shows categories in breadcrumbs of products.

The problem is when product has more than 5 categories - it looks ugly.

My question is: How to show ONLY 5 categories?

Thanks!

```
                <?php
                $term_list = '';
                $j=0;
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    if($term->parent==0){
                        $j++;
                        if( $j <= 1 ){
                            $term_list .= '<a href="'.home_url() . '/' . $category_slug . '/'. $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(strlen($term_list) > 0){ 
                $size = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );
    echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<div class="nav-back">' . _n( 'Back to','Back to', $size, 'tdl_framework' ) . '', '</div>' );
                };
            ?>
```

Comment: Are you coding your own Breadcrumbs? Or, are you using an Add-on?  It would almost be better suited as a question at: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
$terms = array_slice( $terms, 0, 5 );
```

just before the `foreach` to trim it to 5 elements max.